# Native calling interface: how to translate "wchar_t"?

Tags: ncurses, ffi, raku, nativecall

I would like to use the ncurses `int addwstr(const wchar_t *wstr);` function in Perl6.

How could I get a Perl 6 signatures which conveys `const wchar_t *wstr` of `addwstr`?

```
use v6;
use NativeCall;

constant LIB = 'libncursesw.so.5';

sub addwstr(  ?  ) returns int32 is native(LIB) is export {*};
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it would be `Str is encoded('utf32')` on linux.

Comment: ElderBug: This gives me: "Unknown string encoding for native call: utf32 in ..." (on linux).

Comment: I'm not really a perl guy so I'm not sure. `wchar_t` on linux is UTF-32. Maybe it will work with `'UTF-32'` ?

Comment: Reading `NativeCall.pm6` it looks like the utf32 encoding is not recognized by the native call engine.

Comment: Seems like it's a dead end. Does it work for you if you use `addstr` instead of `addwstr`, with `Str is encoded('utf8')` ? Or maybe you could convert yourself to UTF-32 in perl, then pass to `addwstr` as an array of `int32`.

Comment: With `Str is encoded('utf8')` I still don't get the right output and when I try it with an array I get an error: `This representation (CArray) cannot unbox to a native string`

Comment: Did you use `addstr` with utf8 ? I think you have to link `libncurses` instead of `libncursesw`. About the array, how does it knows the native expect a string ? Did you provide the signature somewhere ? I don't think it can read that from the '.so'. You should provide more details (maybe someone else could help you faster, but as for me, I need details). Also, add the attempts you did in the question (easier to follow for me and others who might help).

Comment: Maybe I understood what you did for the array. Did you properly put the definition as `sub addwstr(  CArray[int32]  )` ? Also, if you did the conversion yourself, make sure there is a terminal 0 at the end of the array (idk if perl do that already for its strings).

Comment: If you know a way to make this work, could you please post it as an answer.

Comment: I don't know for now. You should add your tries to the question, because I'm not sure what you actually tried, so I don't really know what really doesn't work. Add some code where you use the function too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wchar_t` is 32 bits on my machine.  From the [NativeCall doco](http://doc.perl6.org/language/nativecall#Arrays), you can declare an array of them and the array name will act as the pointer;

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6
use v6;
use NCurses;                   # To get iniscr(), endwin() etc
use NativeCall;

# Need to run setlocale from the C library
my int32 constant LC_ALL = 6;           # From locale.h
my sub setlocale(int32, Str) returns Str is native(Str) { * }

constant LIB = 'libncursesw.so.5';
sub addwstr(CArray[int32]) returns int32 is native(LIB) { * }

# The smiley        : Codepoint 0x263a
# Latin space       : Codepoint 0x20  (Ascii decimal ord 32)
# Check mark (tick) : Codepoint 0x2713

my CArray[int32] $wchar_str .= new(0x263a, 0x20, 0x2713);

setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
initscr();
move(2,2);
addwstr( $wchar_str );
nc_refresh;
while getch() < 0 {};
endwin;
```

This prints "☺ ✓" on my machine.  It doesn't work without the call to setlocale.

As an aside, you don't *have* to use the 'w' functions - you can just pass normal perl6 strings (presumably encoded UTF-8) and it just works.  This produces the same result;

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6
use v6;
use NCurses;
use NativeCall;

# Need to run setlocale from the standard C library
my int32 constant LC_ALL = 6;           # From locale.h
my sub setlocale(int32, Str) returns Str is native(Str) { * }

my $ordinary_scalar = "☺ ✓";

setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
initscr();
move(2,2);
addstr( $ordinary_scalar );   # No 'w' necessary
nc_refresh;
while getch() < 0 {};
endwin;
```

Comment: I don't think this is portable. On Windows, `wchar_t` is a `uint16` according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/midl/wchar-t